# How to mix and play back multiple audio tracks from a video file?

Tags: ffmpeg, mplayer, libav

I have a video file (in an `mkv` container) with multiple audio tracks (`aid=1,2,...`). Using either `mplayer` or `mpv`, how can I play two of the audio tracks simultaneously (ideally being able to set each track's volume separately)?

I discovered the `--af=lavfi` audio filter bridge to libavfilter, and the `amix` filter, but I can't piece the syntax together correctly. For example, when I try

```
 mpv --af=lavfi='[amix=inputs=2]'
```

I get an error that there aren't enough inputs for `amix`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple inputs or outputs use `--lavfi-complex`. This example is from `man mpv`:

```
mpv --lavfi-complex='[aid1][aid2]amix[ao]' input.mkv
```

- A label of the form `aidN` selects audio track `N` as input (e.g. `aid1`).
- A label named `ao` will be connected to the audio output.

Example with [volume filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume):

```
mpv --lavfi-complex='[aid1]volume=0.5[vol1];[aid2]volume=3dB[vol2];[vol1][vol2]amix[ao]' input.mkv
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! (I had seen the manual, but hadn't synced my checkout before building, and so I was confused why that command line flag didn't work. D'oh.)